# Automatically connect an Openconnect VPN connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, password, vpn, openconnect

I installed the `network-manager-openconnect` package and uses it to login to my Openconnect VPN server. The connection works, except that every time I start the connection a two step dialog box pops up and asks for my VPN username and password:

[image]

This is the first dialog which asks for the username. If the username is correct, it'll go to the second dialog and ask for the password.

Is there a way to provide the VPN username and password in a configuration file so that it doesn't ask for it every time? This is important since I'm trying to make this machine headless.

Or alternatively is there a way to have `network-manager-openconnect` get the username and password from the keyring, and have the keyring be automatically unlocked after login? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Beta 2.

Comment: I'm not sure OpenConnect works that way.

Comment: If you run 'man network-manager-openconnect' does it display any options such as --passwd-on-stdin where you could use a shell script to echo your username and password into the network-manager-openconnect so it would auto-connect on boot? When I google the package, I don't see it's man page available online.

Comment: I'm getting "No manual entry for network-manager-openconnect" unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

Does `openconnect` work for you?

If so you can use this to connect automatically:

```
sudo openconnect SERVER --no-cert-check -u USERNAME --passwd-on-stdin  <PASS_FILE
```

or

```
echo PASS | sudo openconnect SERVER --no-cert-check -u USERNAME --passwd-on-stdin
```

Comment: in ubuntu `18.04` openconnect does not have `--no-cert-check`, any suggestions ?

Comment: @MehrdadPedramfar For newer `openconnect` version after you enter this answer's code, error message give you the `cert` code. and you can use it.